# Associação com escopo em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Possuo uma aplicação Ruby on Rails na qual tenho licenças, items que podem ser licenciados e uma tabela que relaciona os dois (Quais items em que quantidade estão presentes na licença?). Analogamente aos items de um carrinho de compras.

Alguns dos items não serão mais comercializados, porém pretendo mantê-los no banco de dados. Criei então um *soft-delete* e utilizei um escopo padrão para o modelo e para as relações. Porém quando tento alterar os registros já existentes utilizando o modelo relacionado, recebo uma exceção: `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord`

Meus modelos são assim:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(deleted:false) }
end

class LicenseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :license, touch: true
  belongs_to :item
end

class License < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :license_items,  
          -> { joins(:item).where(items: {deleted: false} ) }, 
          dependent: :destroy
end
```

Desta maneira:

```
pry(main)> License.find(0).license_items[0].readonly?
=> true
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer com que este relacionamento não seja somente leitura?

Já tentei adicionar `readonly(false)` no fim do escopo do `has_many` em `License` sem sucesso.

Comment: Qual a versão do Rails você está usando?

Comment: Estava usando 4.0.0, update para 4.0.2 resolveu!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com [essa discussão no GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11199), isso é um bug do Rails 4.0, que foi corrigido na versão 4.0.1. Atualizando seu Rails, você poderá incluir o `readonly(false)` no seu escopo e irá funcionar:

```rb
class License < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :license_items,  
          -> { joins(:item).where(items: {deleted: false}).readonly(false) }, 
          dependent: :destroy
end
```

Para atualizar a versão do Rails, edite seu `Gemfile` e depois execute `bundle update`.

Em último caso, se você não tiver como atualizar a versão do Rails, você pode passar a opção `readonly: false` para o método `find` (não recomendado):

```rb
License.find(1).license_items.find(1, readonly: false).update_attributes(amount: 5)
```

Comment: Update para 4.0.2 resolveu! Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Qual a versão do RoR você está usando? De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/639844/520779) no SO em inglês, quando o recurso "read-only" foi introduzido (na versão 1.12.10) o comportamento padrão era inferir `:readonly => true` sempre que `:joins` era utilizado (o que vejo ser o caso com seu `license_items`). Traduzindo livremente a partir do [CHANGELOG](https://raw.github.com/rails/rails/3-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG) (ênfase minha):

> *1.12.0* (October 16th, 2005)
>
> - Introduzido registros somente-leitura. Se você chamar `object.readonly!` ele vai marcar o objeto como somente-leitura e lançar `ReadOnlyRecord` se você chamar `object.save`. `object.readonly?` indica se o objeto é ou não somente-leitura. Passando `:readonly => true` para qualquer método *finder* vai marcar os registros retornados como somente-leitura. **A opção `:joins` agora implica em `:readonly`, então se você usar essa opção, salvar o mesmo registro vai falhar**. Use `find_by_sql` como um caminho alternativo.

Entretanto, a partir das versões 2.3.4 e 3.0.0, o comportamento mudou: `readonly` somente é inferido se a opção `:joins` for utilizada sem um `:select` **explícito** ou sem a opção `:readonly` [atribuída como false] também explícita (o que, se entendi bem, você já tentou). Em alguns casos (`has_and_belong_to_many`), o `:readonly` é ignorado - explícito ou não - de modo que a única saída é usar o `:select`.

A resposta referenciada acima contém mais detalhes, mas infelizmente não tenho experiência suficiente com o `:joins` para comentar. Sugiro usá-la como ponto de partida se os passos acima não resolverem.